# How do I iterate through a JSON structure with Handlebars

Tags: html, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to build a menu from some JSON using handlebars expressions. I need help figuring out how to iterate through the json to access the data values.

Here's what I have now:

```
<ul>Pseudo HTML Code for Menu 
    {{#each}}
        <li>
            {{menuGroup.parentMenuName}}
            <ul><li>menuItems.subMenuName</li></ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>

{  Pseudo JSON
   "menu":[  
      {  I have 6 of these arrays and I want to get the Parent menu name and description placed into each li tag
         "menuGroup":{  
            "parentMenuName":"MAIN",
            "description":"myDesc",
            "displayOrder":1,
            "menuCategory":"myCat",
         },
         "menuItems":[  
            {  
               "subMenuName":"Payments",
               "shortCode":"PAY"
               "key":"primaryKey"
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Ultimately, for each {Object} within "menu", I would have an "li" tag filled with data from the nested objects. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not super familiar with handlebar expressions.

Update:

In other words, I have a structure like this {{menu.[0].menuGroup.parentMenu}}. I can get the value this way perfectly. For one item. How do I loop through to get the value from all 6 arrays. Not just [0] (the first)

Comment: Is that JSON or an object literal?

Comment: The menuItems was an array of Objects if that's what you were referring too. Earlier I thought there was a link to another similar post. That post wasn't precisely identical to my question, but it helped me get a better understanding of handlebars. If that was you, before an edit perhaps, Thanks! (Please repost the link)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined the menuItems as an array of Objects that is why your code is not working.

```
"menuItems":[  
        {  
           "subMenuName":"Payments",
           "shortCode":"PAY"
           "key":"primaryKey"
        },
     ]
```

Either change this to

```
"menuItems": {  
    "subMenuName":"Payments",
    "shortCode":"PAY"
    "key":"primaryKey"
}
```

Or write the template as

```
<li>
    {{#menuItems}}
        {{subMenuName}}
    {{/menuItems}}
</li>
```

And your code should work.

Working example can be found here. http://jsfiddle.net/prabhat_rai/mhb1supn/

Comment: Thanks, Prabhat! Your explanation and code sample has helped! However, I'm now noticing that my loop stops after the second. For example, my output for the {{menuGroup.parentMenuName}} based on your jsfiddle is "MAIN, MAIN1, MAIN, MAIN, MAIN, MAIN" Oddly enough the menuItems loop perfectly. Any idea why the parentMenuName loop fails after the second?

Comment: Can you give me a fiddler link so that I can check the code once

Comment: Actually, (this is funny), upon closer inspection of the JSON code, I noticed the data I received changed from what I initially started working on and expected. There is no problem with the code. :) Thanks again for your assistence!